# Duplicate results from a LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to look for members that are active in table A, and make sure they are in the appropriate usergroup in a table B.  Rows returned should be the mismatches: active users that are NOT IN group 56, OR inactive users that ARE IN group 56.

Table B is essentially just a table of foreign keys, and users will show up multiple times depending on how many groups they're assigned to.  I only care about group 56.

I've got it working, except for the fact that I'm getting multiple rows returned for each user corresponding to the total number of groups they're in.

```
Table A                  Table B
-----------------        ------------------------
m_id|name|email|active   group_id | user_id | etc
 01 |Abby|a@b.c|  1         01    |   01    | etc
 02 |Bob |b@b.c|  1         56    |   01    | etc
 03 |Carl|c@b.c|  1         56    |   02    | etc
 04 |Dan |d@b.c|  0         02    |   02    | etc
                            66    |   02    | etc
                            99    |   02    | etc
                            01    |   03    | etc
                            56    |   04    | etc
```

MySQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM B LEFT JOIN A
ON B.user_id = A.m_id
WHERE (B.group_id = 56 AND A.active != 1) 
OR
(B.user_id NOT IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT B.user_id FROM B 
LEFT JOIN A ON B.user_id = A.m_id 
WHERE B.group_id = 56) AND A.active = 1)
```

Comment: Do you only need the users list?

Comment: Yes, returned results only needs to display the user and his/her columns.  Good point I hadn't thought of, and I'll need to think a while on how I that affects what I need to write.

Comment: Try with SELECT DISTINCT A.*    This won't get the B table and will discard repeated rows from A.

Comment: Bingo!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach can be simplified and *may lead to a more efficient solution*, by using `Group By` with conditional filtering using `Having` clause.

We will use [`Sum()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) function with a conditional check whether `group_id = 56` for a row. It will return 1 or 0, depending on whether it is true or false. If we want a particular condition to happen atleast once, then `Sum()` of this condition should be more than 0, and *vice versa*.

```
SELECT tA.m_id, 
       tA.name, 
       tA.email, 
       tA.active 
FROM tableA AS tA 
LEFT JOIN tableB AS tB 
  ON tA.m_id = tB.user_id 
GROUP BY tA.m_id, 
         tA.name, 
         tA.email, 
         tA.active 
HAVING 
  (tA.active = 1 AND 
   NOT SUM(tb.group_id = 56)) -- active and no row having group_id = 56
        OR 
  (tA.active = 0 AND 
   SUM(tb.group_id = 56))  -- inactive and atleast one row having group_id = 56
```

Comment: Does removing subqueries automatically equate to greater efficiency?

Comment: @Strawberry well it depends. not all the time; Correlated subqueries are efficient though.